# Получение строк с AsyncTask во фрагмент

Tags: android, android-fragment, android-asynctask, httpurlconnection

Я пытаюсь получить строку/строки с AsyncTask во фрагмент, но появляется ошибка:

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference

В AsyncTask я передаю строки с URL, получаю их с использованием HttpURLConnection.

GetBusinessURL.java (HttpURLConnection) - происходит "сборка URL" (generateURL), затем в "getResponseFromUrl" принимается сформированный URL, по нему будет происходить запрос, и получать ответ:

```
public class GetBusinessURL {
    private static final String GET_RSS_POLITICS = "https://www.pravda.ru/politics/export-articles.xml";

    public static URL generateURL(){
        Uri builtUri=Uri.parse(GET_RSS_POLITICS);

        URL url=null;
        try {
            url=new URL(builtUri.toString());
        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return url;
    }

    public static String getResponseFromUrl(URL url) throws IOException {
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection=(HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        try {
            InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            Scanner scanner=new Scanner(in);
            scanner.useDelimiter("\\A");

            boolean hasInput=scanner.hasNext();
            if (hasInput){
                return  scanner.next();
            }
            else {
                return null;
            }
        }
        finally {
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
    }
}
```

APITask.java (Класс AsyncTask) - В классе APITask, в методе doInBackground получаю на вход url (generateURL с GetBusinessURL), в Business присваиваю то что должно прийти по URL.

```
public class APITask extends AsyncTask<URL, Void,String> {

    private String Business = null;
    private String Economy = null;

    public APITask(String Business, String Economy) {
        this.Business = Business;
        this.Economy = Economy;
    }

    public APITask() {

    }

    public String getBusiness() {
        return Business;
    }

    public String getEconomy() {
        return Economy;
    }

    protected String doInBackground(URL... urls) {
        try {
            Business = getResponseFromUrl(urls[0]);
            Economy = getResponseFromUrl(urls[1]);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

BusinessFragment.java - сюда я пытаюсь передать Business для дальнейшей работы

```
public class BusinessFragment extends Fragment {

    APITask apiTask = new APITask();

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    String data = apiTask.getBusiness(); //в переменную data записываю то что находится в переменной Business (APITask)

    }


public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        apiTask.execute(GetBusinessURL.generateURL());//запускаю AsyncTask и передаю generateURL() с GetBusinessURL
    }
}
```

Comment: Скорее всего просто не успевает сетевой запрос исполниться.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб , а что в таких случаях делают?

Comment: Нужно менять мышление. Нельзя написать синхронный код, который будет работать с асинхронно получаемыми данными. Надо так написать код, чтобы он выполнился только после получения данных. Для этого весь код, завязанный на данные из сети напишите в onPostExecute

Comment: @ЮрийСПб , просто я получаю xml строку и делаю парсинг, а таких строк несколько и я не особо представляю как это уместить в одном onPostExecute

Comment: Проблема не вполне ясна. Кажется, нет смысла парсить вне doInBackground. Однако это никак не решит проблему того, что, наверное, данные вам надо как-то отобразить. И сделать это кроме как в onPostExecute - невозможно (возможно, конечно, но боже упаси вас так делать).

Comment: @ЮрийСПб , понял, буду думать как сделать парсинг в onPostExecute. Спасибо большое

Comment: Возможно, вы не правильно поняли) onPostExecute будет на основном потоке выполняться и, если выполнятся будет долго - приложение повиснет и предложит его закрыть. Парсинг стоит также в doInackground делать (ну или в отдельном AsyncTask, что будет, скорее всего, излишним в вашем случае (к тому же AsyncTask сам по себе устарел и никем не используется (что не делает его изучение бесполезным, т.к. все замены так или иначе реализуют одну и ту же идею - непоследовательное исполнение кода))).

Comment: Тут важно не где парсинг происходит, но когда. Точнее - у вас не будет доступа к полученным с сети данным до тех пор, пока не вызовется метод onPostExecute. А это может произойти даже и через несколько минут, если интернет слабый. Вам просто надо смириться с тем, что вы не можете ничего сделать с данными так, как вам это привычно, т.к. после вызова execute метода данных на следующей строке не будет. Как не будет их и когда будет вызван следующий метод жизненного цикла фрагмента/активити. Это сложно да, но нельзя нормально программировать, не изменив способ мышления в этих случаях.